# How do I join two tables using two columns as parameter for the join?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one for content and one for images.

My problem is: the image is not a required field, but if the image does exists, the column i.type would have to be some specified number.

The query I'm using also returns content from some other tables which has the same id (I know it's wrong, but it's all I have now).

Here is the query

```
SELECT e.*, i.imagem, i.folder
FROM event e
LEFT JOIN img_rel i ON e.id = i.rel
WHERE e.slug = 'slug'
AND e.type = 'even';
```

Is there any way to do that or will I have to filter it using PHP?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are asking. But I suspect you want to include a predicate on `i.type` in the ON clause, e.g. **`ON id.rel = e.id = i.rel AND i.type = 'some specified number'`**. (By including the predicate in the ON clause, it remains an "outer" join. If you put that predicate into the `WHERE` clause, it would negate the "outerness" of the join. I suspect that's the issue you are having. (When a matching row is not found, the columns from `i` in the SELECT list will be NULL.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would

```
join ... on ... and (i.imagem IS NULL or i.type = 'myspecialvalue')
```

be what you need?

Comment: +1  I'm not sure how you get accepted without getting an upvote, so have one on me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` in your query

```
SELECT 
  e.*,
  CASE
    WHEN i.imagem IS NOT NULL 
    AND i.type = 'your number' 
    THEN i.imagem 
    ELSE NULL 
  END AS imagem,
  i.folder 
FROM
  event e 
  LEFT JOIN img_rel i 
    ON e.id = i.rel 
WHERE e.slug = 'slug' 
  AND e.type = 'even';
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be less performant than just adding another condition to the ON clause?

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many columns as you want for the On clause of a Join.  You can even put static filters on the Join.

```
Select * 
From   Table1 t1 Left Join
       Table2 t2 On t1.col1 = t2.col2 
                And t1.col2 = t2.col2
                And t1.col3 = 'something static'
Where  t1.col1 = 'this will match both col1 and t2.col1'
```